# Implementation of queue in data structure

Tags: java

What is wrong with my code? I can't run it apparently. Below is  my coding. Can somebody help me find the error?

Implement the Queue to do the following operations:

1. Enqueue(‘a’);
2. Enqueue(‘b’);
3. Enqueue(‘c’);
4. Enqueue(‘d’);
5. Enqueue(‘e’);
6. Enqueue(‘f’);
7. Enqueue(‘g’);
8. Enqueue(‘h’);
9. Dequeue();
10. Dequeue();
11. Dequeue();
12. Dequeue();
13. Enqueue(‘i’);
14. Enqueue(‘j’);
15. Dequeue();
16. Dequeue();

    ```
    public class Queues {

    public static void add(Queues <String>myQueue, String s) {
       myQueue.enqueue(s);


    public static void main(String[] args){

            Queues myQueue = new Queues (20, 0, 0);
            myQueue.Enqueue('a');
            myQueue.Enqueue('b');
            myQueue.Enqueue('c');
            myQueue.Enqueue('d');
            myQueue.Enqueue('e');
            myQueue.Enqueue('f');
            myQueue.Enqueue('g');
            myQueue.Enqueue('h');
            myQueue.Enqueue();
            myQueue.Enqueue();
            myQueue.Enqueue();
            myQueue.Enqueue();
            myQueue.Enqueue();
            myQueue.Enqueue();
            myQueue.Enqueue('i');
            myQueue.Enqueue('j');
            myQueue.Enqueue();
            myQueue.Display();
        }                 
     }

    class Queue{
    int x;
    char [] y;
    int front, rear, w;



    Queue (int a, b , c);
    x = a;
    y = new char[x];
    front = b;
    rear = c;
    w = rear;

           boolean CHK_Q_EMPTY()
           return rear == 0;
           }
           boolean CHK_Q_FULL(){
           return rear == x;
           }


     void Enqueue (char d){
          y(rear) = d;
            rear++;
            w++;
     }

    void Dequeue(){
       for (int z=1; z<rear; z++){
           y[front]=y[z];
           front++;
       }  


          w--;
          if(front == rear){
            front = 0;
            rear = w;
          }
    }
          void display(){


             for (int i=0; i<rear; i++)
                System.out.println(y[i]);
             }
            }
    ```

Comment: Is this your real code? It doesn't compile. First correct all the compilation errors, then run it, correct as much of it as you can, paste your new cod, and then let us know what is it supposed to do and what it is doing wrong.

Comment: don't know where the errors are :/ im just a beginner :'(

Comment: Then it's too early for you to be using StackOverflow. You need to read your Java books. To look at each compilation errors that you get and compare it to what the book says should be there, and then fix it. Doing so on StackOverflow is nearly impossible because it's not an interactive site. If you need a human to help you, you should talk to your instructor or his assistant.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define named functions inside other functions. If I were you I would make `main` a `runnable` lambda expression.

Also, methods `CHK_Q_FULL`, `Enqueue`, `Dequeue`, and `display` access undefined variables.

`Queues` needs a constructor with three arguments. The default constructor never takes more than zero arguments. `Queue`'s constructor needs a body. The argument's types need to be specified. Below the constructor are three statements that access undefined variables. Also in the `main` method you use the undefined function `Display`. You should probably overload the method Enqueue too.

Comment: i didn't get it...im just a beginner, can you explain it in a more simple language?

Comment: @user2971157 You should probably do what RealSkeptic said. If you want quick online information on how to code in Java, I would recommend the Java tutorials. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). Just try to correct compiler errors first.